# Difference between pre-equilibrium and steady-state approximation?

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics

Both are reaction mechanisms in which there are several steps and at least one intermediate present. However, I am confused about the differences of both methods, especially when using them to determine rate laws. Also, in which types of reactions can we apply each of the methods?

Comment: See the related page on [chem.libretexts.org](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Kinetics/03%3A_Rate_Laws/3.02%3A_Reaction_Mechanisms/3.2.02%3A_Pre-equilibrium_Approximation)

Comment: See also https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/110794/is-there-a-difference-between-equilibrium-and-steady-state